# How to test new feature in development server

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket, production, staging

I'm new to web development and I'm struggling to understand how I can test new features added by other people to my web application before pushing the commit to the site.

My web application uses heroku and bitbucket. So far, only one person at a time has been working on the site and I push the commits to heroku master to see the changes.

But now, I want to test a new feature which a freelancer has added to my web application BEFORE pushing the commits to heroku master.

How do I do this?

I found that I need to first set up a "staging" or "production" server on heroku so I forked my app, and set up a heroku remote, so now I have two identical apps on heroku.

The next part is what I don't understand, how can I see the changes which are commited by the freelancer in bitbucket but only in the forked app so it doesnt affect the app which is live.

here is what my sourcetree looks like:

[image]

Hope this makes sense and I apologise is any of the terms are used incorrectly.

Here is

Comment: I did not use heroku before and not really familiar with the services provided, but I can suggest reading on git as this is going to help you understand (and therefore, divide a problem into smaller ones easier to solve and build a better work-flow). This tutorial looks great! https://learningpassion.wordpress.com/2016/06/15/git-tutorial-day-to-day-use-part-1-intro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is [Heroku Pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines) which allow you to have several environments representing different branches of the same codebase.

Comment: Question - does it matter if my repo is in Bitbucket? All the information on Heroku Pipelines are linked to GitHub.